# What's the significance of the "this" keyword in this nested function

Tags: javascript, function-composition

This function computes `f(g(...arg))` in JavaScript.

```
function compose(f,g){
   return function(...arg){
       return f.call(this, g.apply(this, args)};
   }
}
```

I know that the first argument to the methods `call` and `apply` is the invocation context. However, I am not sure what's the significance of the `this` keyword in both `call` and `apply` methods above. It's clearer to me when the invocation context is an object like `{x:1}`, and then we use could use `this.x` to access the property `x`, but I am not clear on the use of `this` in the above context. Why do we use `this` like that in the above code?

EDIT: the functions are called with these functions:

```
const sum = (x, y) => x + y;
const square = x => x * x;
compose(square, sum)(2, 3);
```

Comment: In your specific case, it refers to the anonymous function itself. You can also look at the answers to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: @Seblor it doesn't? As always, it depends on how it's called.

Comment: Since the anonymous function doesn't have any properties, it would be pretty pointless if it *was* the value of `this` (which, as VLAZ points out, it isn't).

Comment: @VLAZ I fail to see how it could not refer to the anonymous function with this snippet. I would genuinely be interested to see a case where it would not be the case.

Comment: @Seblor `this` pretty much never refers *to a function*. Look at the link you posted. It depends on *how the function is called*. The vast majority of time it's something like `obj.foo()` which calls `foo` with `this = obj`. Calling *just* `foo` will not set a `this` context (the results vary between strict and non-strict mode). Explicitly supplying a `this` parameter through `.call`/`.apply` is the only way to make it refer to a function but that's also seldom done.

Comment: @VLAZ — Well. Since functions are objects you can also have a function as a property of another function and then: `firstFunction.otherFunction()` but that's also seldom done. (I think jQuery is the only example I can think of and it overloads absolutely everything in ways I wouldn't recommend).

Comment: @VLAZ I added how and where the function is called. What's the value of `this` in this case? The invocation context I think is the global object, right? If yes, what is the significance of using `this` in the above code? In other words, what would happen if I put `null` in its place? It's (`this`) not being used in the functions, right?

Comment: @VLAZ ah, right. I made a wrong assumption in my mind at some point. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because we want to *preserve* the original calling value of `this` and forward it to all composed functions.

This doesn't matter if we compose together functions that do not use `this` as is your example:

```
const sum = (x, y) => x + y;
const square = x => x * x;
compose(square, sum)(2, 3);
```

Here, `this` is irrelevant.

However, the composition is generic and should apply to any pair of functions. We *could* use `this`, in which case it's good to preserve how they work in case it matters:

```js
function compose(f, g){
   return function(...args){
       return f.call(this, g.apply(this, args));
   }
}

function introduce(greeting) {
  return `${greeting}! My name is ${this.name}.`;
}

function addRandomFact(str) {
  return `${str} I like ${this.hobby}.`;
}

const person1 = {
  name: "Alice",
  hobby: "pancakes",
  introduce: introduce,
}

console.log(person1.introduce("Hello"));

const person2 = {
  name: "Bob",
  hobby: "turtles",
  introduce: compose(addRandomFact, introduce)
}

console.log(person2.introduce("Hola"));
```